# How do I remove frontpage content block?

Tags: 7, blocks

I am trying to remove the main page content page. I made a views slider (block) which I then displayed on the frontpage. However, I am finding it difficult to remove the mainpage content block. I am using drupal 7 and the zen subtheme.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove the `content` part of a page as it is not a block. The content is suppose to be your main content that always shows and blocks are things that can be conditionally shown around your content.

You can create a page display for your view, then change the front page of your Drupal site to point to your views page display (D7: admin/config/system/site-information, D6: admin/settings/site-information).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to remove the default front page: Just make a new page that you want as front page, and click 'make front page' option.

You might need the Panels module for that.